# Three.js canvas texture power of 2 but cropped

Tags: canvas, three.js, html5-canvas, sprite

In Three.js it's best practice to keep textures to be a power of 2, and actually a requirement for some older Chrome browsers e.g.
32x32, 64x64 etc

Therefore I need to create a canvas texture of power of 2 dimensions, but I need to have that Sprite clickable, which means it needs to be cropped somehow.

Consider this example:

[image]

- Black bg is the Three.js renderer
- Red bg is the required size of a canvas (to power of 2)
- White bg is the size of the text

I would like to keep the texture at dimensions power of 2, but crop it to only show the white area. This is so the user can hover on the label for example. I don't want them hovering on the red area!

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var config = {
  fontface: 'Arial',
  fontsize: 32,
  fontweight: 500,
  lineheight: 1,
};
var text = 'Hello world!';

function nextPowerOf2(n) {
  return Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)));
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = `${config.fontweight} ${config.fontsize}px/${config.lineheight} ${config.fontface}`;
const textMetrics = ctx.measureText(text);
var textWidth = textMetrics.width;
var textHeight = config.fontsize * config.lineheight;
canvas.width = nextPowerOf2(textWidth);
canvas.height = nextPowerOf2(textHeight);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, textWidth, textHeight);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.textAlign = 'left';
ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
ctx.font = `${config.fontweight} ${config.fontsize}px/${config.lineheight} ${config.fontface}`;
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);

console.log('canvas', canvas.width, canvas.height);
console.log('text', textWidth, textHeight);

var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  map: texture
});
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
sprite.scale.set(spriteMaterial.map.image.width, spriteMaterial.map.image.height, 1);
scene.add(sprite);


var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

How is this possible? Somehow cropping the SpriteMaterial?

Comment: FYI: It is not and never has been any different on old browsers. Also, please use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and please use a versioned CDN for three.js otherwise your example will break in a few weeks and be useless.

Comment: Have updated to use cdn and snippet. There are different/older builds of Chrome which don't support it '251[.WebGL-0x86d0ad00]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.' see the thread at: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/17879

Comment: I see nothing in that thread that suggests what I wrote is incorrect. WebGL has always has a power-of-2 requirement for filtering and still has it today. That hasn't changed since it shipped 9 years ago.

Comment: Oh sorry... I meant that Android 7.1 Chrome throws a JavaScript error preventing the canvas from rendering, where-as on more modern browsers only show a texture resize warning. Understand it's always been best practice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the texture's repeat so only the portion of the canvas used covers the sprite

```
texture.repeat.set(textWidth / canvas.width, textHeight / canvas.height);
```

Then you can set the size of the sprite to just that portion

```
sprite.scale.set(textWidth, textHeight, 1);
```

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var config = {
  fontface: 'Arial',
  fontsize: 32,
  fontweight: 500,
  lineheight: 1,
};
var text = 'Hello world!';

function nextPowerOf2(n) {
  return Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)));
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = `${config.fontweight} ${config.fontsize}px/${config.lineheight} ${config.fontface}`;
const textMetrics = ctx.measureText(text);
var textWidth = textMetrics.width;
var textHeight = config.fontsize * config.lineheight;
canvas.width = nextPowerOf2(textWidth);
canvas.height = nextPowerOf2(textHeight);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, textWidth, textHeight);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.textAlign = 'left';
ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
ctx.font = `${config.fontweight} ${config.fontsize}px/${config.lineheight} ${config.fontface}`;
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);

console.log('canvas', canvas.width, canvas.height);
console.log('text', textWidth, textHeight);

var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
texture.repeat.set(textWidth / canvas.width, textHeight / canvas.height);
var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  map: texture
});
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
sprite.scale.set(textWidth, textHeight, 1);
scene.add(sprite);


var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also may need to set the texture offset after changing the repeat
texture.offset = new THREE.Vector2(0, 1 - (textHeight / canvas.height));

Comment: You can just use `texture.offset.set(x,y)`